# Not able to access variables in required file

Tags: javascript, gulp, require, browserify

I'm using browserify on a project and am running in to the following:

I have a file test.js. In test.js there is nothing but the following:

```
var test = 'test';
```

Now, in the same directory I have my main file 'app.js'. I require test.js and try to access the 'test' like so:

```
var testing = require(./test.js);
alert(test);
```

This fails and the console returns 'test is undefined'.

Now, I did try putting this in 'test.js' instead:

```
module.exports = {
    test: 'test'
}
```

and the in app.js:

```
var testing = require(./test.js);
alert(testing.test);
```

and this does work but it isn't what I want. I don't want to have to define every single variable, function, etc. in an object. I want the entire file of test.js code to to be written in by gulp before the code in app.js as if it were a server include or as if both files were in the 'head' element and test.js was written in first.

Is this sort of behavior even possible?

Comment: *"Is this sort of behavior even possible?"* It might with some custom pre-processing script, but that would make your code harder to maintain. E.g. in every file that includes `test.js`, you would have to remember which variables are declared in that file, so that you don't accidentally override them. You basically want global variables, but there is a reason why global variables should be avoided. If you simply want to "auto-export" all defined variables, that's not possible. Maybe you should look into ES6 module definitions, which would allow you to write `export var test = 'test';`.

Comment: But that is how CommonJS modules are supposed to work ... you could use global variables though (bad practice). Google -> Node.js global variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without custom logic, it's not possible to achieve what you want. However I believe you could find a compromise by using [ES6 modules](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html) instead of CommonJS modules.

You would be able to write

```
export var test = 'test';
```

which declares and exports a variable `test`. You can then import it with

```
import {test} from './test';
```

Since you are using browserify, plugging in an ES6 module to CommonJS converter is pretty straightforward. E.g. you could use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).